# Debugging the code executed on a new thread

Tags: ollydbg, debugging

I would like to step into some code which is ran on a new thread. Luckily, after the initial startup this is the only thread that is newly created in the program. I can set the debugger to break on the creation of a new thread. But all I see is the WinAPI and lower level calls that execute the thread. How can I step into the code that is executed on the thread to see what it does?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

BP on `CreateThread`, then see 3rd parameter -> `lpStartAddress` of the Thread (its EntryPoint). Now simply BP on that address and step from there when it breaks

Comment: That seems so obvious, and works great, thanks :)